# I want to receive information from the user from discord, but I don't know what to do. ( discord.py )

Tags: python, discord

I want to receive information from the user from discord, but I don't know what to do.

I want to make a class to input data

if user write !make [name] [data], bot generate class A, A(name, data)

The following is the code I made. What should I do?

Ps. command_prefix is not working properly. What should I do with this?

`

```
import discord, asyncio
import char # class file
from discord.ext import commands

intents=discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Game"))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "test":
        await message.channel.send ("{} | {}, Hello".format(message.author, message.author.mention))
        await message.author.send ("{} | {}, User, Hello".format(message.author, message.author.mention))
    
    if message.content =="!help":
        await message.channel.send ("hello, I'm bot 0.0.1 Alpha") 
    async def new_class(ctx,user:discord.user,context1,context2):
        global char_num
        globals()['char_{}'.format(char_num)]=char(name=context1,Sffter=context2,username=ctx.message.author.name)
        char_num+=1
        await ctx.message.channel.send ("done", context1,"!")

client.run('-')
```

`

Answer (score 0):

***I advice to not using on message for making commands***
what I do advice:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
    
@bot.command(name="name here if you want a different one than the function name", description="describe it here", hidden=False) #set hidden to True to hide it in the help
async def mycommand(ctx, argument1, argument2):
      '''A longer description of the command


    Usage example:
    !mycommand hi 1
     '''
    await ctx.send(f"Got {argument1} and {argument2}")
```

if you will use the two ways together then add after this line

**await message.channel.send ("hello, I'm bot 0.0.1 Alpha")**
this:

```
   else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

if you want to make help command u should first remove the default one
by editing this line `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)` to :

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents,help_command=None)
```

overall code should look like

```
import discord, asyncio
import char # class file
from discord.ext import commands

intents=discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents) 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents,help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("Game"))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    async def new_class(ctx,user:discord.user,context1,context2):
        global char_num
        globals()['char_{}'.format(char_num)]=char(name=context1,Sffter=context2,username=ctx.message.author.name)
        char_num+=1
        await ctx.message.channel.send ("done", context1,"!")

@bot.command()
async def make(ctx,name,data):
    #do whatever u want with the name and data premeter
    pass
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello, I'm bot 0.0.1 Alpha")
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
        await ctx.send ("{} | {}, Hello".format(ctx.author, ctx.author.mention))


client.run('-')
```

and yeah if u want to know what is ctx
ctx is context which is default premeter and have some methods like send,author and [more](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context)